# How to ajaxable validate a PasswordChangeForm?

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

I have some forms that I want to validate with an ajax view.

```
class ProfileEditPasswordForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class AjaxValidation(generic.edit.FormView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        data = []
        for k, v in form._errors.iteritems():
            text = {
                'desc': ', '.join(v),
            }
            if k == '__all__':
                text['key'] = '#%s' % self.request.POST.get('form')
            else:
                text['key'] = '#id_%s' % k
            data.append(text)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return HttpResponse("ok")

    def get_form_class(self):
        form_dict = {
            'signup': forms.RegisterForm,
            'signin': forms.LoginForm,
            'safety': forms.ProfileEditPasswordForm
        }
        return form_dict[self.request.POST.get('form')] #=> TypeError
```

As you can see, I have 3 different forms. First two work just fine. But the third one returns me an error.

> `__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

I believe that it happens because my form requires a user to validate his old password, so I did this:

```
'safety': forms.ProfileEditPasswordForm(user=self.request.user)
```

And know it throws another error:

> `'ProfileEditPasswordForm' object is not callable`

And here I stuck.

---

```
Traceback:
File "***/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "***/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "***/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "***/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  213.         form = self.get_form()
File "***/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  74.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/validate/
Exception Value: 'ProfileEditPasswordForm' object is not callable
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
csrfmiddlewaretoken = u'MjSRpY4NQsTuv6hG8HLYZYI3n9HpPU4R'
form = u'safety'
old_password = u''
new_password1 = u''
new_password2 = u''
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The code above generates the error

Comment: I mean the exact line that created the error. it's hard to tell by just looking at those. And then the full traceback

Comment: i've read docs you need to return super from form valid not httpresponse, like this return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)

Comment: check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

Comment: @AnatolyStrashkevich I'm sorry, but this is not the case. And you can return whatever you want since form_valid returns `HttpResponseRedirect`. Check out the source code of Django https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L104

Comment: i see, but shouldn't you call super anyway (before return)?

Comment: @AnatolyStrashkevich you should call it if only you want to return `HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that django `FormView` is not compatible with `PasswordChangeForm`. The form requires the user to be passed to its constructor, but the view will not do that. You could try overriding `get_form_kwargs` method like this:

```
class AjaxValidation(generic.edit.FormView):
    # your methods
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AjaxValidation, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

The `kwargs` will be passed to form constructor and it should work. `get_form_class` is OK in your main code example

Comment: I'm sorry, I fogot to tell that I'm using Python 2.7